# Change download url depending on browser

Tags: php, javascript, html

What I want to do is have a normal link for desktop browsers like so:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <a href="http://db.tt/b6ecH2Dh">
      <img src="img/download.gif"/>
</div>
```

But when a iOS user clicks the link it should open a different link like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <a href="cydia://package/bla">
       <img src="img/download.gif"/>
</div>
```

Could I do it with JavaScript or PHP? if so how?

EDIT
To do it with javascript, put this script INTO THE  OF YOUR HTML DOC

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i)) {
                document.getElementById('down').href="http://www.google.com";
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I'd suggest having a quick google for "Mobile Device Detection" or something of that nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) 
{
     document.getElementById('download_link').href = "http://iphonedl";
}
```

Should work

http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone

Comment: ok so i can put that into the <script type="text/javascript"></script> tags in the head of the html doc but what do i put into the body so it displays? sorry im new to web code

Comment: Yep, in the <script> tags. Don't forget to assign an ID to the link.

Comment: it dosnt work then :( im trying a diffrent method atm i think yours dosnt support ipod touchs

Comment: well it seems it detects its an ios device but dosnt change the download? i set the id like this <div style="text-align: center;"><a id="download_link" href="http://db.tt/b6ecH2Dh"><img src="img/download.gif"/> is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with both:

- [PHP](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/p/http_user_agent.htm)
- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

For examples, see http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad